# Creating An iPhone App For My Company Portfolio

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

Can I create a company portfolio kind of an app for Apple App Store. I want to create this app as a representation of my company. Like it will contain contents regarding what other apps we have created, a contact page and all the other stuff which a normal Company Website contains.

Plus as far as In-House App Program is concerned, my understanding is that those apps are only viewable to the limited number of users who are chosen. I want to create an app that would display my company's portfolio to any one who comes on App Store and write the name of my company.

Will apple approve this kind of app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they follow their own guidelines for reviewing, they won't approve it.  However, interpretation is obviously flexible or else a lot of existing apps wouldn't be there.

Quote:

2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

2.13 Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected